# Passing options to a chart

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Using AM Charts 4, the way I have been using charts until now is I do something like

```
var categoryAxis = this.__chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 120;

var valueAxis = this.__chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = 'Y-AXIS:;
valueAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;
```

Is there a way to put all the options into a single object and pass that one object in? In that case if I wanted to add another option I would just have to update the object, not add a line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using JSON config: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/json-config/
However, if you want to change things after you build a chart, the method you use is much more effective, as with JSON config you'll have to rebuild the chart instead of changinf only the thing you need.

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a shot but it isnt working for me. Can you tell me where Im going wrong? https://codepen.io/conormdowney/pen/NVNMZG

Comment: You have PieChart series type, it should be PieSeries: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/YbWaNw